# In Angular 2+, is it possible to put all the routing information in one routing module file?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2+, is it possible to put all the routing information in one routing module file, including all the children. Like is it possible to put all the children and children of children and children of children of children in one routing module file while separating each routes into modules with lazy loading?

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'path1', loadChildren: 'app/path/path.module#PathModule',
  children:[
    {
      path: 'path2', loadChildren: 'app/path2/path2.module#Path2Module', 
      children:[{
        path: 'path3', component: 'SomethingComponent',  
      },
      {
        path: 'path4' , loadChildren: 'app/path4/path4.module#Path4Modue'
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So the above is the type of configuration I want to make. I am wondering if the nesting of children with loadChildren and children is possible all in one file just as it shows above. I want to do this so that all the Router configuration for the app is in one file.

Comment: need an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: yes, if you want to define all routes beforehand the type of configuration that you showed will work just fine. also, you might want to read this great article on modules [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)